# Does Cesium JS offer support for saving the users current instance of the viewer?

Tags: reactjs, cesiumjs

What I'm looking to achieve is the ability to save the users current state/session of their cesium instance so that when they go onto the website at a later date, they're able to continue where they left off.

The user will have the ability to import their own custom layers to the app, and so saving their session means they won't have to keep importing everything again.

Does Cesium/Resium offer support for this, or is there a similar 3D viewer that I could use instead?